# How to detach DataTable Header so it can scroll with the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a JS JQuery DataTable, it is really long.  Normally if you have a long table, you can set DataTable to be scrollable.  However in my case, the layout is such that I need the page to be scrollable and the table to be not scrollable (ie, completely displayed).  The problem in this case then is that I can't get the header to scroll with the webpage.  I was thinking if there is a way to detach the header from the table, I can put it somewhere static, is this possible?

Comment: FixedHeader perhaps ? http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/index.html

Comment: Better than nothing I suppose but it does not scroll the table controls, just the column headers.  I will use it if there are no other options.

Comment: You mean like this? http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/top_bottom_left_right.html

Comment: Yep, I implemented the FixedHeader add-on and modified it such that it also fix the control bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the FixedHeader add-on and modified it such that it also fix the control bar.   Thanks to ManseUK and Nico Hämäläinen for the tips.